# How to use different validation rules on same entity in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

Problem:
How to save object Account as nested object when only ID is needed without getting ConstraintValidator exception?

Problem is because i have set validation rules to class, but when i want to save sem entity as nested object i get exception that some property values are missing. So i would liek to have different validation rules when i want to persist object as a whole and when i want to use it only sa nested object (when only ID is needed).

```
public class Account {  
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String userName;
    //getters&setters
```

If I include Account as nested object i just need ID to be able to use it as FK (account entity is already in DB), but because of @NotNull annotation i get Exception.

Is there a way to ignore those annotations from Account when trying to save object Shop or how to create different validation rules for Account to validate just soem other properties and not all?

```
public class Shop { 
    private int id;

    private Account owner; // only ID is needed
```

Do you have any basic example? I dont understand those in documentation. I have already read documentation before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at Bean Validation groups where you can classify specific validations so they are only activated when that group is validated and ignored otherwise.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups) for details.

Taking an example from the documentation:

```
// This is just a stub interface used for tagging validation criteria
public interface DriverChecks {
}

// The model
public class Driver {
  @Min(value = 18, message = "You must be 18", groups = DriverChecks.class)
  private int age;
  // other stuffs
}
```

A group is nothing more than a *tag* that allows you to enable/disable validations based on specific use cases at run-time.  By not specifying the `groups` attribute on a bean validation annotation, it defaults to the `Default` group, which is what Bean Validation uses if a group-tag isn't specified at the time of validation.

That means the following holds true:

```
// Age won't be validated since we didn't specify DriverChecks.class
validator.validate( driver );

// Age will be validated here because we specify DriverChecks.class
validator.validate( driver, DriverChecks.class );
```

This works great when  you're triggering the validation yourself inside your service methods because you can manually control which group checks are applicable based on that method's use case.

When it comes to integrating directly with Hibernate ORM's event listeners that can also trigger bean validation, group specifications become a bit harder as they must be specified based on the event-type raised by hibernate.

```
javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist
javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update
javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove
```

For each of the above properties you can specify in the JPA properties supplied to Hibernate, you can list a comma delimited list of groups that are to be validated for each of those event types.  This allows you to have varying checks during insert versus update versus removal.

If that isn't sufficient, there is always the fact that you can create your own constraint validator implementation and annotation to plug into Bean Validation and specify that at the class or property level.

I have often found this useful in cases where values from multiple fields must be validated as a cohesive unit to imply their validity as the normal field-by-field validations didn't suffice.

Comment: Do you have any basic example? I dont understand those in documentation. I have already read documentation before posting here.

Comment: Added more clarity for you.  I didn't go into how to exactly create your own custom constraint validators but I believe the documentation is clear on that.